# Lighting not working in a 2D JavaFX game when using subtracting shapes?

Tags: java, 2d, lighting, javafx

So im trying to add lighting into my game.  I'm using shape subtracting and unions to subtract circles (the lights) from a dark rectangle that covers the whole world.  I think that its a problem with how i'm subtracting and unifying shapes, but i really don't know.  Its really just inverse clipping with multiple objects.  Here's the method with the adding/subtracting shapes:

```
    public static void setInverseClip(final Rectangle node, final Group clip) {
        Shape union = (Shape) clip.getChildren().get(0);
        for (int i = 1; i < clip.getChildren().size(); i++) {
            Shape.union(union, (Shape) clip.getChildren().get(i));
        }
        final Rectangle inverse = new Rectangle();
        inverse.setWidth(node.getWidth());
        inverse.setHeight(node.getHeight());
        node.setClip(Shape.subtract(inverse, union));
    }
```

So what this is doing is that it makes a new shape, combines it with other shapes in the group, and then it subtracts it from a rectangle.

Here's the whole `Lighting.java` class:

```
package sample;

import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Shape;

import static sample.World.s;
import static sample.World.worlds;

public class Lighting {
    static Lightmap[] lightmaps = new Lightmap[worlds.length];
    static Rectangle[] skylights = new Rectangle[worlds.length];

    public static void setInverseClip(final Rectangle node, final Group clip) {
        Shape union = (Shape) clip.getChildren().get(0);
        for (int i = 1; i < clip.getChildren().size(); i++) {
            Shape.union(union, (Shape) clip.getChildren().get(i));
        }
        final Rectangle inverse = new Rectangle();
        inverse.setWidth(node.getWidth());
        inverse.setHeight(node.getHeight());
        node.setClip(Shape.subtract(inverse, union));
    }

    public static void calculateLighting(int wn, double skyLighting) {
        lightmaps[wn] = new Lightmap();
        Block[][][] world = worlds[wn];
        skylights[wn] = new Rectangle();
        skylights[wn].setWidth(worlds[wn].length*s);
        skylights[wn].setHeight(worlds[wn][0].length*s);
        skylights[wn].setFill(Color.color(0,0,0, 1-skyLighting));
        for (int z = 0; z < worlds[Player.cw][0][0].length; z++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < worlds[Player.cw][0].length; y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < worlds[Player.cw].length; x++) {
                    Block b = world[x][y][z];
                    if (b.embID == 1) { //if the block has a torch attached to it
                        CircleLight light = new CircleLight();
                        light.setRadius(s*5);
                        light.posX = x*s - (int)light.getRadius()/2;
                        light.posY = y*s - (int)light.getRadius()/2;
                        lightmaps[wn].getChildren().add(light);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (lightmaps[wn].getChildren().size() != 0) {
            setInverseClip(skylights[wn], lightmaps[wn]); //clips the rectangle to the lightmap
        }
    }
}

class Lightmap extends javafx.scene.Group {}

class CircleLight extends javafx.scene.shape.Circle {
    public int posX = 0;
    public int posY = 0;
}

/*class RectLight extends javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle {
    public int posX = 0;
    public int posY = 0;
}*/
```

Here's where im actually using it in the main update loop:

```
Lighting.skylights[Player.cw].setX(0 - Camera.getX());
        Lighting.skylights[Player.cw].setY(0 - Camera.getY());
        Lightmap lightmap = Lighting.lightmaps[Player.cw];
        for (int i = 0; i < lightmap.getChildren().size(); i++) {
            if (lightmap.getChildren().get(i).getClass().getName().equals("sample.CircleLight")) {
                lightmap.getChildren().get(i).relocate(((CircleLight)lightmap.getChildren().get(i)).posX - Camera.getX(), ((CircleLight)lightmap.getChildren().get(i)).posY - Camera.getY());
            }
        }
        if (Lighting.lightmaps[Player.cw].getChildren().size() != 0) {
            Lighting.setInverseClip(Lighting.skylights[Player.cw], Lighting.lightmaps[Player.cw]);
        }
```

Only one light is appearing, and it's not in the right place